# Declaring a pointer to a temporary buffer on the stack in a single line?

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

In the following code, `getDriverNames()` is declared as `getDriverNames(char **names, long maxDrivers)`, where the `names` is required to be an array of 32-character string buffers to receive available driver names (I only care about the first available driver).

Is there a way to declare the `names` variable without the intermediate `buffer`?

```cpp
char buffer[32+1] = {};
char *names[1] = {buffer};
asioDrivers->getDriverNames(names, 1);
return asioDrivers->loadDriver(names[0]);
```

Comment: According to Visual Studio: arguments of type "char (*)[33]" are incompatible with type "char **" for that when passed to getDriverNames

Comment: `loadDriver` can be `loadDriver(buffer)` but if `getDriverNames` is expecting an array of pointers to arrays, then I don't think you can skip having a `names`. `&buffer` would be an rvalue expression whose address can't be taken, so you can add an extra `&` to get a second level of indirection. I believe you need that pointer to exist as an lvalue, which means you'll need a named object.

Comment: getDriverNames((char**)&buffer, 1); was a success!!!

Comment: @norlesh "Compiles" is not the same as "works". `(char**)` is an explicit type conversion, it basically tells the compiler to be quiet and not tell you that your conversion isn't correct. You can get terribly incorrect code to compile with liberal use of explicit type conversions, but it still won't work. `getDriverNames((char**)123, 1);` will also compile, but it is clearly wrong.

Comment: I stand corrected, although the function call went through I just noticed there was no result copied!

Comment: It seems like you could do `asioDrivers->getDriverNames(&unmove(+buffer), 1); return asioDrivers->loadDrivers(buffer);`, with `template<typename T> T& unmove(T&& v) { return v; }`, but your current code seems fine as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getDriverNames()` function expects a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays. It is going to follow the pointers. So no, there is no way to declare all of that inline, you need the individual arrays to be allocated before you can take their addresses.

```
         names    buffer
         -----    --------------------
param -> | 0 | -> | 0 | 1 | ... | 32 |
         -----    --------------------
```